# What statistical test would be the most useful for a 3 x 2 table when more than 20% of cells are less than 5?

Tags: chi-squared-test, contingency-tables

What statistical test would be the most useful for a 3 x 2 table when more than 20% of cells are less than 5?

Chi square testing requires a min of 80% of cell counts to be over 5.

For example, if I was wanting to see if room colour effected mood and these were my results.

.............Happy........Sad.........Hopeful

Black............2.............4..................25

Blue..............16...........2..................3

Comment: what is your null hypothesis? that there is no association between mood and room colour? If that's the case, you can use a Freeman-Halton extension of the fisher test

Comment: If you're prepared to condition on the margins (as is required for the Fisher exact test), you can as easily do an exact test based on the chi-squared statistic, based on sampling the possible tables with the given margins; R implements this for its chi-sqaured test by choosing `simulate=TRUE`. While both exact tests can tend to be conservative if you insist on a 5% (or 1% etc) significance level - due to lack of available significance levels in tables with low counts - it won't be an issue in this case; your table will have an extremely low p-value in any case (if you simulate enough tables)

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to test the null hypothesis that the row value is statistically independent of the column value.  This can be done using [Fisher's exact test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test), which conditions on the marginal totals of the categories.  (Hat-tip to [Glen_b](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/805/) for pointing this out.)  This can be implemented in `R` as follows:

```
#Set up the contingency table for the data
DATA <- matrix(c(2, 4, 25, 16, 2, 3), nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE);
rownames(DATA) <- c('Black', 'Blue');
colnames(DATA) <- c('Happy', 'Sad', 'Hopeful');

#Perform Fisher's exact test
TEST <- fisher.test(x = DATA);

#See the results of the test
TEST;

        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  DATA
p-value = 1.344e-07
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

Unsurprisingly, there is extremely strong evidence to reject the null hypothesis of independence (which was already pretty obvious from looking at the numbers in the table).